# How to convert sorted Arraylist to BST

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, binary-search-tree, element

I have the following code to work with, how could make this method create a BST. I am working Elements.I am using custom imports that can do "T.setRoot()","n.getRightChild()","n.setLeftChild()" and so on, which shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

```
public static <E> BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L) {

     BTree<E> T = new BTree<E>();
        //TODO
     return T;
 }
```

How could i make a recursive method to go through the Arraylist of elements and add them do the BST. I would like to keep this structure intact. All the examples i found were used while the arraylist contained integers, that makes implementing them in element form very difficult. The BST has to be balanced.

I have tried to following:

```
private static <E> BTree<E> buildRecursively(ArrayList<E> L,E start,E 
  end,BTree<E> T){
     if (start.compareTo(end) < 0)
         return T;
     E x = L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size() % 2));
     T.setRoot(new BTreeNode<E>(x)); 
     T.setLeftChild(buildRecursively(L, start, L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size()  
     %  2)-1)),T);
     T.setRightChild(buildRecursively(L, L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size() % 
    2)+1), 
    L.get(L.size()-1)),T);
```

But this obviously this didnt work.

This is what i am currently working with:

```
  public static <E> BTree<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> L) {

     BTree<E> T = new BTree<E>();

     E root = L.get((L.size()/2) + (L.size() % 2));
     T.setRoot(new BTreeNode<E>(root));


     return T;
}
```

Not sure where to go from here. I am supposed to somehow traverse the arraylist from x to find the element for the 2 children and do that recursively. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you'd a) implement your BST (Add, Find, Delete, etc), then b) copy elements from your original source (it can be *anything* - not just a "sorted Arraylist") one at a time.  Q: "Copy each" is your only choice, isn't it?  ALSO: You'd need to implement [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for non-int values.

Comment: The issue is it also has to be balanced.

Comment: `public static <E> Set<E> taulukostaPuu(ArrayList<E> list) {
     return new TreeSet<E>(list);
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx) it's a good start to understand BST, in case you talk about simple BST.

Comment: It's definitely a  to better understand BSTs, first, before writing any code.  John's example is in C# (should be OK); here's an example specifically for Java: [Implementing a Binary Tree in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree).  See also [Java Program to Create a Balanced Binary Tree of the Incoming Data](https://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-create-balanced-binary-tree-incoming-data/)